# To combine two summary queries that use a common group by into one query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, summary

I am having an absolute brain lock on this query and was wondering if anyone could assist me.

I have daily data in 1 ms access table in the form: 
clients (unique) |  date | openingbal | closingbal | 
I have a SQL to get the no. of daily client balances that closed higher than they opened (increase)

```
SELECT Dates, Count(closingbal) AS Increases FROM tablename 
WHERE closingbal >[ openingbal] GROUP BY Dates
```

This works ok.

I also have one for client balances that closed lower than they opened (decrease):

```
SELECT Dates, Count(closingbal) AS Decreases FROM tablename 
WHERE closingbal <[ openingbal]GROUP BY Dates
```

This works ok too.
I am totally stuck on how to combine these two queries into one query in the form:

```
Date | Increases | Decreases |
2013-08-22 | 1748 | 743 |
2013-08-23 | 1145 | 112 |
2013-08-24 | 1640 | 912 |
```

Any assistance with this query is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How 'bout using Union

```
Select Dates, Sum(Increases), Sum(Decreases)
from
{
    SELECT Dates, Count(closingbal) AS Increases, 0 as Decreases FROM tablename 
    WHERE closingbal >[ openingbal] GROUP BY Dates

    Union All

    SELECT Dates, 0 as Increase, Count(closingbal) AS Decreases FROM tablename 
    WHERE closingbal <[ openingbal]GROUP BY Dates 
}
GroupBy Dates
```

Comment: This has worked, and such a quick response. Thank you very much, much appreciated!